# What is derivative of Matrix with respect to a Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I want to calculate the derivative of dot product of two Matrices of not the same order.

$X = \begin{bmatrix}x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}\\x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{32}\end{bmatrix}$

$y= \begin{bmatrix}y_{11} & y_{12}\\y_{21} & y_{22}\\y_{31} & y_{32}\end{bmatrix}$

Problem is I can't figure out What does it mean to derivative of matrix with respect of matrix individual elements.
I tried to use the sum notation to calculate derivative of a single element of the resultant matrix.

$c_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^na_{i,k}\cdot b_{k,j}$

$\frac{\partial (X y)_{11}}{\partial X} =
\begin{bmatrix}y_{11} & y_{12} & y_{21}\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

and the other partial Derivatives are similar to this.
I want to know that what is

$\frac{\partial Xy}{\partial X} = ?$

I can't figure out how to get this when the element derivative itself is a matrix.
and the matrices as inputs are not even of the same order.

Comment: The expression $\frac{\partial (Xy)}{\partial X}$ cannot be interpreted as a matrix in a "natural" way. Because $Xy$ and $X$ are matrices, this derivative is really a fourth-order tensor (whereas a vector is first-order and a matrix is second-order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$Xy = \mathrm{vec}(Xy) = \mathrm{vec}(IXy) = (y\otimes I)'\mathrm{vec}(X)$$ take the derivative wrt $\mathrm{vec}(X)$ to obtain $y\otimes I$. This is consistent with the comment of Ben Grossmann as it is the "vectorization" of said fourth order tensor.

Comment: what if that resultant matrix is taken as an input to function and which sums all the elements and outputs a single real value.
how will calculate the derivative of this nested function sum(dot(X, y)) with respect to X?
will this be possible to calculate?

Comment: I got the answer of the above comment.

Comment: I think I cant really follow..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you have a scalar function $(\phi)$ defined as follows
$$\eqalign{
C_{ij} &= \sum_{k=1}^p X_{ik}Y_{kj} \\
\phi &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}
  \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^p X_{ik}Y_{kj} \\
}$$
This can be written in matrix notation using an *all-ones* matrix $J$ the same size as $C$.

In this form, the gradient is very easy to calculate
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= J:XY \\
d\phi &= J:dX\,Y \;=\; JY^T:dX \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= JY^T \\
}$$

---

In the above, a colon is used as a convenient product notation
for the trace function
$$A:B = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The product can be applied to vectors by treating them as rectangular matrices (set $n=1$) in which case it's just the dot product.
The terms in such a product can be rearranged in a number of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
 A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB  \\
}$$
due to the properties of the underlying trace function.